# plan a route in prolog

Tags: prolog, routes

What i wan to do is find a route with some givin facs. i've done some research and i allready know that i have to add a basic step and recursief step. that i've implemented but it does not work when i have to transfer. So if it are neighbours, it works, but not otherwise.

this is what i have:

```
p(zwolle,apeldoor,36).
p(apeldoorn,zutphen,22).
p(hengelo,zwolle,60).
p(zutphen,hengelo,45).
p(arnhem,apeldoorn,30).
p(arnhem,zutphen,24). 


%basic step
route(Begin,End,PastCitys):-
       not(member(End,PastCitys)),
   p(Begin,End,_).

%recursief
route(Begin,End,PastCitys):-
  p(Begin,Stepover,_),
      not(member(Stepover,PastCitys)),
  route(Stepover,End).

plan(Begin,End):-
   route(Begin,End,[Begin]).
```

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here are three hints in ascending order of complexity:

1. You misspelt 'apeldoorn' once, so the obvious test `route(zwolle,apeldoorn)` doesn't work purely because of that.
2. You need to express the fact that neighbourship is symmetrical, so that you can find a route from A to B whether that fact is expressed one way or the other.
3. You can still get into an infinite loop with unlucky inputs before you find a route even if one exists. For that you need an 'occurs check' that prevents you from getting into cycles when taking the recursive step.

Comment: so i've added a check, but still does not work, i know that it isn't bidirectional. But thats for later on.
Do you anything else that can help me out?

Comment: These two changes are really all that's standing between you and success. If you get a wrong answer, trace the call and compare what happens with what you expected would happen. If you can't figure out what's different, edit your question and post the example.

Comment: @JorneDeBlaere Do not forget that predicate `route` should have three attributes while it seems to have two in the recursive clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). Just code it with Prolog. The method with recursion and list of visited nodes is not optimal at all (see Richard O'Keefe, "The Craft of Prolog", chapter 5.4). But usually the warshall algorithm is already present in a graph manipulation library, you need study how to use it.